# XSLT Transformation For Each Complex Condition

Tags: html, xml, xslt, foreach

I want to transform this xml

**XML**:

```
<Page>
  <Sections>
    <Section id="parent_hdr_sec" rows="2" columns="1">
      <Sections>
        <Section id="plan_hdr" rows="0" columns="0" />
        <Section id="plan_hdr_dtl" rows="0" columns="0" />
      </Sections>
    </Section>
    <Section id="splitter_sec" rows="1" columns="2">
      <Sections>
        <Section id="parent_left_sec" rows="4" columns="1">
        </Section>
        <Section id="parent_right_sec" rows="7" columns="1">
        </Section>
      </Sections>
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</Page>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="Page/Sections/Section">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <table>
                  <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="@rows"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="Columns" select="@columns"/>

                  <xsl:for-each select="(//Section/Sections/Section)[$Rows >= position()]">
                    <tr>
                      <xsl:for-each select="(//Section/Sections/Section)[$Columns >= position()]">
                        <td>
                          <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                          </xsl:attribute>
                        </td>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

**My Output**:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="parent_hdr_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="splitter_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr"></td>
              <td id="plan_hdr_dtl"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Correct Output**:

'id' variable value wrongly updated in my output.

I need output like this below,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="parent_hdr_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr_dtl"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="splitter_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="parent_left_sec"></td>
              <td id="parent_right_sec"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want XSLT for each condition to get the above output.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish with the `$Rows` and `$Columns` variables. One thing that seems clear is that within each branch, you only want to handle the nodes that belong to that branch - so you should **not** start your *select* expressions with `//`.

Try perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="Page/Sections/Section">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <table>
                  <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="@rows"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="Columns" select="@columns"/>

                  <xsl:for-each select="Sections[$Rows >= position()]">
                    <tr>
                      <xsl:for-each select="Section[$Columns >= position()]">
                        <td>
                          <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                          </xsl:attribute>
                        </td>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that:

```
<td>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- more -->
</td>
```

can be written shortly as:

```
<td id="{@id}">
    <!-- more -->
</td>
```

see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting output like this, if I use the above one

Comment: <html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="parent_hdr_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="plan_hdr"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="splitter_sec">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="parent_left_sec"></td>
              <td id="parent_right_sec"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: @Hari Please don't post code in comments, it's quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Sorry..to post in comments section....☺